# MySql MAX(DATE(Transaction_Date)) returns different type than DATE(MAX(Transaction_Date))

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.8, pymysql

I have a MySql 5.7 transaction table with a `DATETIME` column, `Transaction_Date`, that is indexed. My Python 3.8.5 program is interested in retrieving the maximum transaction date on the table (ignoring the time portion). There are two possible queries (maybe even more):

```
select date(max(Transaction_Date)) from `transaction`
```

and

```
select max(date(Transaction_Date)) from `transaction`
```

However, depending on which query I use, `pymysql` or `mysql.connector` (it doesn't matter which one I use) returns me a different data type as the result, i.e. a `date.datetime` instance for the first query and a `str` for the second:

**The Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `Transaction_ID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Transaction_Date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `transaction`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Transaction_ID`),
  ADD KEY `Transaction_Date` (`Transaction_Date`);
```

**The Program:**

```
import pymysql


database = 'xxxx'
user_id = 'xxxx'
password = 'xxxx'

conn = pymysql.connect(db=database, user=user_id, passwd=password, charset='utf8mb4', use_unicode=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('select date(max(Transaction_Date)) from `transaction`')
row = cursor.fetchone()
d = row[0]
print(d, type(d))

cursor.execute('select max(date(Transaction_Date)) from `transaction`')
row = cursor.fetchone()
d = row[0]
print(d, type(d))
```

Prints:

```
2021-01-19 <class 'datetime.date'>
2021-01-19 <class 'str'>
```

Can anyone explain why a `datetime.date` is not returned for the second query? For what it's worth, I have another table with a `DATE` column and when I select the `MAX` of that column I am returned a `datetime.date` instance. So why am I not returned a `datetime.date` for a `MAX(DATE(column_name))`?

**Update**

```
mysql> create temporary table t1 as select max(date(Transaction_Date)) as d from `transaction`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.20 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show columns from t1;
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| d     | date | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is what I would expect, so it is quite a puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through `pymysql` source and some MySQL documentation. It looks like the database server returns field descriptors, which the module then uses to set a class on the value, there are various converters available: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/converters.py. At the bottom, it maps field types to the method.

The database server is describing `max(date)` as a VAR_STRING, so the module proceeds accordingly. I'm not sure of the specific reason for this description, which I suppose is the core of your question. It would take some digging through MySQL source, the documentation is not very detailed.

As a workaround, casting the result to a date does make it work as expected:

```
select cast(max(date(Transaction_Date)) as date) from transaction
```

Comment: The same phenomenon occurs when I use two other connectors and Python 2 so it would appear that MySQL is returning what you say but what I would think is the incorrect data type for `max(date(datetime-column))`. For what it's worth, the first query is also the more efficient one in that it just uses the index. But tell me, how did you determine that the server was describing the second query as returning a VAR_STRING? See my update to my post where I create a temporary table from the second query and do a `show columns` which shows the expected `DATE` type.

Comment: I altered the local module in a few spots to print to console. While running the query, it printed the server-supplied column type, which corresponded to VAR_STRING as defined by  https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py.

Comment: That was creative. It's still hard to reconcile it returning VAR_STRING given that it creates a DATE column when doing `create temporary table t1 as select max(date(Transaction_Date)) as d from `transaction``.

Comment: @Booboo oddities like that are why I switched to Postgres 10y ago :)